# memory corruption due to #pragma pack error - std map corruption- crashing on insert

Tags: c++, stl, crash

I have a project I am working on where I have some strange behavior with the std maps.

I had my own typedef map defined which mapped strings to a pointer of a custom type. The application crashed anytime that I excess the map after I add the first pair to the map.

After a lot of messing around I changed the map to a  and moved it to the first call in my application and it still crashes. I have no idea what could be going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that crashes at the moment.

```
LoggerPtr syslogger(Logger::getLogger("CISInterface"));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::map<string, string> MyMapDef;
    MyMapDef tmpString;
    tmpString.insert(MyMapDef::value_type("0000", "d"));
    tmpString.insert(MyMapDef::value_type("1111", "d")); //Crashes here.
    tmpString.insert(MyMapDef::value_type("2222", "d"));

//  std::string configFile;
//  int c;
//  if(argc < 2)
//  {
//      //Must have c option
//      std::cout << "Usage -c configFileName" << std::endl;
//      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//  }
//Rest of main commented out. 
...
```

And here is the stack trace -

```
CISInterface Debug [C/C++ Application]  
    gdb/mi (10/31/12 6:02 PM) (Suspended)   
        Thread [1] (Suspended: Signal 'SIGSEGV' received. Description: Segmentation fault.) 
            6 std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const()  0x00000032fd49c416    
            5 std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() basic_string.h:2317 0x0000000000417ec7 
            4 std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::operator() stl_function.h:230 0x000000000041706f  
            3 std::_Rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_insert_unique() stl_tree.h:1170 0x0000000000415d00    
            2 std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::insert() stl_map.h:500 0x00000000004150eb   
            1 main() CISInterface.cpp:29 0x000000000041916d 
gdb (10/31/12 6:02 PM)  
/home/cillian/workspace/CISInterface/Debug/CISInterface (10/31/12 6:02 PM)
```

What other areas should I be looking at that could be causing problems. Could it be in the libraries that I'm linking with?  I have created a second project with just these lines of code that links with the same libraries (but doesn't have any code that calls into them.) and it doesn't crash.

Comment: If that code you posted is really all the code, then the **only** thing that can be causing your problem is heap corruption caused by `LoggerPtr syslogger(Logger::getLogger("CISInterface"));`. The code in `main` is correct. Try commenting out that line and see if you still get the crash.

Comment: I just copied your `main()` and ran it here (Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3). No problem so far. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: The only problem that I see in this piece of code is that your `MyMapDef` is a `std::map<string, string>` while it should be `std::map<const string, string>`, because you cannot change a key once you've inserted to a map.

Comment: @Murilo - The map will internally store `pair<const Key, Data>`, so a `map<string, string>` *will* have a const key.

Comment: When you have found the solution to your own problem, it is better to write an answer describing it. And while you remove the solution from your question in another edit, you might change the title to something that describes the actual cause, e.g. "memory corruption due to #pragma pack" or similar. That way, others have a chance to see whether your issue applies to them.

Comment: @user1787720 you can post an answer to your own question, then accept it, and it won't show up as an unanswered question.  Dunno if that is the right way to do it, but it would work!

Comment: Done, sorry guys wasn't too sure how the system works.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

Thought I'd add it here on the off chance anyone else ever does the same thing.

I slowly removed files in my project to try and find the offending file. I was thinking that it must be something defined in a header file that was causing issues (like a static). It took a long time but I think I've found it. I had a header file that defines a number of structs. These are serialized to the wire so I had them 1 byte aligned using #pragma pack (push) which I put at the top of the file and #pragma pack (pop) at the bottom. But I then added a couple of #include statements after the first #pragma definition meaning that these includes were aligned incorrectly and caused some nondeterministic behavior. Thanks everyone that had a look. Should probably use the **attribute** syntax and I wouldn't had the problem. Offending code is below for completeness.

```
#pragma pack (push)
#pragma pack (1)

#include <string> //Wrong place for includes!
#include <Units.h> 

typedef struct 
{ 
....
}
#pragma pack (pop)
```

Thanks to everyone who had a look at initial problem.

Comment: A similar effect can also be caused by forgetting the `#pragma pack(pop)`